# Does addeventlistener("volumechange", ...) work on ios?

Tags: javascript, ios, progressive-web-apps

I am currently developing a PWA. Trying to detect when the user presses the volume up or volume down button on ios to fire my callback function. However, it does not seem to work.

```
 document.querySelector(".audioElement").addEventListener("volumechange", function () { code block })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't use it on iOS because the volume property always returns 1.

From [official Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW1) :

> On iOS devices, the audio level is always under the user’s physical control. The volume property is not settable in JavaScript. Reading the volume property always returns 1.