iPhone 15 safari browser switch event trigger
It is possible to trigger an event eg browser or profile switch  or incognito mode by using the volume up and power buttons in iOS ?
Something is happening when she does this but I can’t pin it ?
I believe I’m watching some body do it but they are keeping it on the low .i don’t write code but i need to learn this .

[so] is for questions about programming. If you don't write code, then this is not the site for you. [su] is for questions about using computers.

Does this answer your question at least about volume control on an iOS device https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66892631/does-addeventlistenervolumechange-work-on-ios Basically the answer is ‘no’.

Can you explain what is meant by power buttons? I can only think of the button that switches the device off, when of course the JavaScript will not be running.

Thank you for your help so far , I know it can be draining educating the newbies .
